# Container Bean to transparently proxy get/set to container

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, javabeans, aop

I've got a Kotlin wrapper data class whose purpose is to wrap arbitrary values with additional information about their state. For the purposes of this question, something like this will suffice:

```
data class Wrapper<T>(val content: T)
```

Unfortunately, sometimes (specifically, in javax validation constraint violation paths) Spring tries to access nested properties directly:

```
data class Name(val first: Wrapper<String>)
data class Person(val name: Wrapper<Name>)

val foo = Person(Wrapper(Name(Wrapper("Steve"))))
```

Obviously, for a value of type `foo`, the property path `name.first` is not defined, as it should be `name.content.first.content` instead. So if Spring receives, say, ConstraintViolation with a path of `name.first` (we wrote a validator to create paths for `Wrapper` this way), it tries to access that path on `foo`. `foo` does have `name` but that's a `Wrapper`, which only has `content`, and not `first`, so Spring throws an exception.

Is there a way to tell Spring that all values of type `Wrapper` have the exact same fields that their `content` has? This kind of feels like AOP and Proxies, but I can't wrap my head around how to make `Wrapper` a Proxy, and if that's possible at all.